# How to initialize a repeated element in protocol buffer?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Assume that I have this message.

```
message A {
  repeated float w = 1 [packed = true];
}
```

How can I initialize w in my Code? Can I do any better than this?

```
a = A()    
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; ++i) 
   a.add_w(0);
```

Comment: Actually the `resize` method exists at `google::protobuf::RepeatedField` but is missing at `RepeatedPtrField`. I had do it your way. Go figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a.w()` or `a.mutable_w()` will return a [`google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField) which provides some additional options. For instance, you could call `a.mutable_w()->Reserve(n)` to pre-allocate space in advance, to avoid the usual strategy of re-allocating every time the size doubles. You can also use `Resize(n)` followed by `mutable_data()` to get direct access to the underlying buffer, but this probably won't provide much speed benefit over `Reserve(n)` followed by your loop.